Kafka Streams - Why can't I aggregate and sum up my Longs?
I'm new to Kafka Streams and I'm trying to cobble together my first application.
I would like to add up the amounts of my BankTransactions.
@Bean
    public KStream<?, ?> kStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
        JsonSerde<BankTransaction> jsonSerde = new JsonSerde<>(BankTransaction.class);
        jsonSerde.configure(Map.of("spring.json.type.mapping", "BankTransaction:nl.sourcelabs.kafkasolo.streamprocessing.BankTransaction"), false);
        return kStreamBuilder.stream("transactions", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde))
        .mapValues((readOnlyKey, value) -> value.amount)
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
                .aggregate(() -> 0L, (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate + value,
                        Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("transactionAmountCount")
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                                .withValueSerde(Serdes.Long()))
                .toStream();

    }

The event is read from the topic and deserialised correctly.
But the app crashes with the following error:
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=transactions, partition=0, offset=0, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by IntegerDeserializer is not 4
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(IntegerDeserializer.java:30)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(IntegerDeserializer.java:24)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.deserialize(ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.deserialize(ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.java:31)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:163)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.outerValue(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:427)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$get$5(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:318)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:887)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.get(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:318)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractReadWriteDecorator$KeyValueStoreReadWriteDecorator.get(AbstractReadWriteDecorator.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.KeyValueStoreWrapper.get(KeyValueStoreWrapper.java:76)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamAggregate$KStreamAggregateProcessor.process(KStreamAggregate.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:152)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:291)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:154)

I don't understand how the LongDeserializer is getting a single byte KeyValueStore when only Longs have been put in it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried debugging the code but all I can see is that the changelog of transactionAmountCount is being read and that that's where everything blows up.

From the error it seems that the deserializer values is defined for integers (4 bytes link).
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by IntegerDeserializer is not 4

If you look carefully at the log, you can see that it indicates is using the IntegerDeserializer.
Ensure you are using the correct deserializer that matches your data and that is correctly configured for both keys and values. Check that there are no conflicting configurations.
Note: From other cases I've seen that if you have previously ran your application with that data type (integer), your changelog topic might still contain the old data serialized as that data type. Just in case, make sure to clear the changelog topic to force the app to use the correct serialization format.

It was indeed stale data coming out of the changelog. But I thought since the changelog topic on kafka was empty (or deleted by me) that the kafka streams app would start from scratch. But it doesn't, the state.dir contains a local cache of the changelog topic which contained corrupt data. Once that was deleted then everything worked perfectly.

I'm glad you got it sorted out!
